# Socket makefile() not responding the second time I call it

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to learn how to use socket.makefile() function, but I am stuck at getting the second response from a server
Here is my test code

```
import socket
S = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
S.connect(('smtp.comcast.net',25))
file = S.makefile('rwb')
line = file.readlines()
print repr(line)
file.write("Ehlo User\r\n")
line = file.readlines()
print repr(line)
```

And here is what I receive when I run it:

```
['220 omta06.emeryville.ca.mail.comcast.net comcast ESMTP server ready\r\n']
[]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I googled alot of results, seems there isn't much documentation over the makefile() function. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `socket.makefile` is a pretty terrible API.  Real networking software never uses it.  A socket is not a file.  Trying to pretend that a socket is a file leads to all kinds of bugs that can only be fixed by *not* pretending that anymore.  I suggest you get comfortable with the rest of the socket API or pick up a higher-level library that makes sockets easier to use without also making their use extremely error prone.

Answer (score 2):

The first call to `.readlines()` reads all of the lines and doesn't return until it has read every single line that will ever be available. When `.readlines()` is called again, there are no more lines to read. Perhaps you should call `.readline()` instead.

Oh, and by the way, don't name your variables after built-in types. It isn't invalid, but it is bad practice.

Try this:

```
import socket
S = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
S.connect(('smtp.comcast.net',25))
server = S.makefile('rwb')
line = server.readline()
print repr(line)
server.write("Ehlo User\r\n")
line = server.readline()
print repr(line)
```